# Audit Table DB Design : Does creating Audit Tables for Join Tables make sense

Tags: database-design, postgresql, join, audit, audit-tables

we are creating separate audit tables for those entity tables which need auditing using triggers on PostgreSQL 8.4.

```
<Family> <Contact> <Family_Contact> <Address>
```

We have some join tables. Eg : Family_Contact is a join table.

Family has 1 or more than 1 contacts. Each contact has  an Address. So, we have the following Table structure.

For auditing a Family, we need the following Tables which are duplicates of the above tables.

```
<Family_audit> <Contact_audit> <Family_Contact_audit> <Address_audit>
```

Family_Contact_audit is an AUDIT Join Table.

QUESTION : Does it make sense to make a separate AUDIT Table for the Join Tables ? Are there alternatives ? We will be using the Audit Tables for reporting purposes.

Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

Yea they still make sense.

You could not track of the alterations made in family contact without an audit table to that particular table.

I don't see any other way that you could track changes and use, without creating these tables separately.